# GCM integration with VPN

Tags: java, android, networking, google-cloud-messaging, vpn

I am working on an android application which only works inside a co-operate on specific devices. The application uses `GCM` to send messages from server to client..!

The issue is that all the devices are setup on VPN `Virtual Private Network` which means the devices can only communicate with the app server. I don't understand, how to configure the VPN to allow the communication between GCM and android device, any help appreciated..!

Comment: The VPN captures all traffic to the Internet and redirects it to the VPN endpoint. Therefore the only thing that needs to be adapted are the firewall rules of the firewall that is located between the VPN endpoint and the Internet.

Comment: @Robert how to work with the firewall rules?

Comment: ask the person operating the firewall